# Mule ESB JPA Hibernate java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, mule

I have a problem..
this:

```
<jpa:query statement="from Dog dog where dog.name = 'Cujo'" config-ref="Java_Persistence_API" doc:name="Java Persistence API"/>
```

WORK!

this:

```
<jpa:find entityClass="domain.Dog" id-ref="#[payload:]" config-ref="Java_Persistence_API" doc:name="Java Persistence API"/>
```

Exception stack is: 1. domain.Dog (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)

Why?

packagesToScan is set up correctly

```
<spring:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <spring:property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateVendor"/>
    <spring:property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="jpaPropertyMap"/>
    <spring:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <spring:property name="packagesToScan" value="domain"/>
</spring:bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the class named 'Dog.java' in your classpath?